# Python Twilio SMS

Tags: python, sms, twilio

I have the following code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import os


account_sid = os.environ["TWILIO_ACCOUT_SID"]
auth_token = os.environ["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

client.messages.create(
    to = "0743157169",
    from_= "0743157169",
    body="Messaj"
)
```

Pycharm recognise twilio library(or package) and when I write some method, the IDE shows me the suggetsions like method ,,messages'' or ,,create''. But every time I run the program this error appears:

```
File "SMS_sending.py", line 1, in <module> from twilio.rest import Client ImportError: No module named twilio.rest
```

I try restart the computer, uninstall twilio, change the python interpreter to 2.7.9 (my current one is 3.4) but nothing.

Comment: How are you installing twilio and how do you run the python program? Is your Pycharm integrated with `virtualenv`?

Comment: sudo pip install twilio, yes it is

Comment: Ok, have you `source`'d the `bin/activate` in the directory in which you are trying to run the program?

Comment: No i dont' have

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds to me like Pycharm is working with `virtualenv` but when you run the program you are not within the `virtualenv` so don't have access to the libraries you have installed in there.

So, on the command line, navigate to your project directory. Then activate the `virtualenv`:

```
$ source bin/activate
```

Then run the program:

```
$ python SMS_sending.py
```

Let me know if that helps.